# Delete all results having count(*)=1 in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, sql-delete

I have table containing quotes and its authors and there are some authors have only on quote.

Now I want to delete all rows that its author exists one time only.

I have tried many solutions but all failed:

**This is my code:**

```
DELETE  FROM `quotes` 
WHERE `qu_author` NOT IN (SELECT `qu_author` 
                          FROM `quotes` 
                          GROUP BY `qu_author` 
                          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Failed in what way?  Error?  Deleted the wrong columns?

Comment: i try it on phpmyadmin and this error message ... #1093 - You can't specify target table 'quotes' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @eng.ahmed, check link above, you cannot reference table that you are deleting from in subquery

Comment: i red the solution in this question but i can't implement it or understand it

Comment: which part you don't understand?

Comment: what is si and so .. generally idn't understand what he do in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this? you mean?
[sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d1bd8/1/0)

Comment: Thank you very much :) .. it's working .. but i cann't understand this code :(

Comment: It's logically the same as your statement, just using a different syntax to get around restrictions.

Comment: Are there any topic or link van you address me to

Comment: is this syntax easier to understand? [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/588d8f/1/0)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html you're probably interested in those statement syntax near the end of the document just before the comments.

Comment: yes the syntax is understandable

Comment: sorry but how can i do it for sqlite because it seems like this syntax is unsupported in sqlite